# Homebew on M1 bin is not in your PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I know there is already a lot of related question with regards to this Homebrew warning but I am getting a different instruction from what most answers I am seeing in the web.

Most answers I am seeing has these commands

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> ~/.zprofile
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Or

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/$yourdevicename/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

However this is what the instruction I am getting from the terminal.

```
==> Next steps:
- Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users /username/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt /homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I am not sure which one should I follow, as of now I executed the commands based on what is in my terminal that includes this `(echo;` part but no idea how can I check if that works and already fixed the problem. I tried `echo $PATH` and this is what it looks like.

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:....
```

What is the difference between these commands or do they all perform the same action? Am I correct to assume that seeing `/opt/homebrew/bin` from echoed PATH means it is success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all do basically the same thing. Some of them are safer than others because of how Posix shells like Zsh and Bash parse commands. For example:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

is safer than

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

If the output of `brew shellenv` contains shell metacharacters (e.g., spaces or dollar-signs) then the latter will probably do something unexpected.

You should try running `brew shellenv` from an interactive shell prompt and trying to understand its output.

P.S., You need to be more careful when copy/pasting text. Some of your copied text has unexpected spaces. Such as this line from your question:

```
eval "$(/opt /homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

The space after `opt` completely changes the meaning of that command.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know why that spaces is there but in the terminal there is no space probably pasting issue from my side when composing my question. But indeed irresponsible copy pasting gave me an issue lately when I tried to copy a recently pasted command from Notes app and didn't know that there is such thing call Smart Quotes in Substitution settings which can really be silly.